# Setting Control properties from separate thread/class

Tags: c#, multithreading, class, listbox

I've searched and can't find a solution that helps me get text from a thread running in a separate class, back to a listbox on the form that created the thread.

Basically I have a class that holds a "test", it is called in it's own thread from a test window.  What I want to be able to do is add text to a listbox on the main form to let the user know what is going on with a test.  All the examples I can find on Invoke show how to do it within the same class.

Where I start the thread:

```
    PermeabilityTest Run_Test = new PermeabilityTest();
    public Thread WorkerThread;

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //enable timer for test duration display
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        //create and start new thread.
        WorkerThread = new Thread(Run_Test.RunTest);
        WorkerThread.Start();
    }
```

Here is my class that actually does the work, where I need to get text back to a listbox on a separate form from.

```
public class PermeabilityTest
{
    //volatile alerts the compiler that it will be used across threads.
    private volatile bool aborted;

    public void RequestStop()
    {
        //handle saving data file here as well.
        aborted = true;
    }

    public void RunTest()
    {
        //reference the comms class so we can communicate with the machine
        PMI_Software.COMMS COM = new COMMS();

        //some test stuffs here
        int x = 0;
        while( x < 100 && !aborted)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Well here it is, running it's own thread." + Environment.NewLine);
            COM.Pause(1);
        }  
    }        
}
```

I would appreciate any one who could help me understand how to get some text back to a listbox on the same form that has the button which starts the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1: (Preffered)** Add an event on **PermeabilityTest** and register on that event in your main form.
Then modify the content of your List box from within your main form.

Example:

Your main form:

```
    PermeabilityTest Run_Test = new PermeabilityTest();
    public Thread WorkerThread;

    public form1()
    {
        // Register on the Progress event
        Run_Test.Progress += Run_Test_Progress;
    }

    void Run_Test_Progress(string message)
    {
    if(listBox.InvokeRequired)
        {
            // Running on a different thread than the one created the control
            Delegate d = new ProgressEventHandler(Run_Test_Progress);
            listBox.Invoke(d, message);
        }
        else
        {
            // Running on the same thread which created the control
            listBox.Items.Add(message);
        }
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //enable timer for test duration display
        timer1.Enabled = true;

        //create and start new thread.
        WorkerThread = new Thread(Run_Test.RunTest);
        WorkerThread.Start();
    }
```

new Delegate:

```
    public delegate void ProgressEventHandler(string message);
```

Modified PermeabilityTest class:

```
    public class PermeabilityTest
    {
        //volatile alerts the compiler that it will be used across threads.
        private volatile bool aborted;
        public event ProgressEventHandler Progress;

        public void RequestStop()
        {
            //handle saving data file here as well.
            aborted = true;
        }

        public void RunTest()
        {
            //reference the comms class so we can communicate with the machine
            PMI_Software.COMMS COM = new COMMS();

            //some test stuffs here
            int x = 0;
            while (x < 100 && !aborted)
            {
                // Report on progress
                if(Progress != null)
                {
                    Progress("This message will appear in ListBox");
                }
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write("Well here it is, running it's own thread." + Environment.NewLine);
                COM.Pause(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Option 2:** 
You could make **PermeabilityTest** an inner class of your main form, and by doing so, allow it to access private members of your main form.
Then you need to pass a reference of your main form to the constructor of **PermeabilityTest** and keep it as a member.

**Option 3:**
pass your list box to the constructor of **PermeabilityTest**

Don't forget to use Invoke on your control since you are running from a different thread.